# How to match against a large collection efficiently

Tags: algorithm

I have a large collection of objects of type `foo`. Each object of type `foo` has say 100 properties (all strings) plus an id. An object of type `bar` also has these 100 properties.

I want to find the matching object of type foo from the collection where all these properties match with that of bar.

Aside from the brute force method, is there an elegant algorithm where we can calculate a signature for `foo` objects once and do the same for the `bar` object and match more efficiently?

The `foo`s are in the thousands and the `bar`s are in the millions.

Comment: [Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darth Vader has a point there... and I never thought that I'd be siding with the dark side!

I'll go over what I think are the best tools for the trade:

- Embedded database: [Google's LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/)- it's faster than most database solutions out there.
- Hashing function: [Google's CityHash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/)- it's **fast** and it offers **excellent hashing!**
- [JSON Serialization](http://www.json.org/)

**The Embedded Database**

The goal of using an embedded database is that you will get performance that will beat most database solutions that you're likely to encounter. We can talk about just how fast LevelDB is, but [plenty of other people have already talked about it quite a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=leveldb%20performance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) so I won't waste time. The embedded database allows you to store key/value pairs and quickly find them in your database.

**The Hashing Function**

A good hashing function will be fast and it will provide a good distribution of non-repeatable hashes. CityHash is very fast and it has very good distribution, but again: I won't waste time since a [lot of other people have already talked about the performance of CityHash](https://www.google.com/search?q=leveldb%20performance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=BfF&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=CityHash%20performance&pbx=1&oq=CityHash%20performance&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=177338l178506l0l178743l9l7l0l0l0l4l262l1379l0.3.4l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=6c73e4a0597c28b0&biw=1467&bih=678). You would use the hashing function to hash your objects and then use the unique key to look them up in the database.

**JSON Serialization**

JSON Serialization is the antithesis of what I've shown above: it's very slow and it will diminish any performance gain you achieved with CityHash, but it gives you a very simple way to hash an entire object. You serialize the object to a JSON string, then you hash the string using CityHash. Despite the fact that you've lost the performance gains of CityHash because you spent so much time serializing the object to JSON, you will still reap the benefits of having a really good hashing function.

**The Conclusion**

- You can store billions of records in LevelDB and you will be able to quickly retrieve the exact value you're looking for just by providing the hash for it.
- In order to generate a key, you can use JSON serialization and CityHash to hash the JSON string.
- Use the key to find the matching object!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

If you have ALL matching properties. That means they are same objects actually. is that correct?

In any case, you want to use a Map/Dictionary/Table with a good hashing algorithm to find matching objects.

Whichever language you are using, you should override the gethashcode and equals methods to implement it.

If you have a good hashing algorithm your access time will be O(1). otherwise it can be upto O(n).

Based on your memory limitation, you want to store foos in the map, storing bars might requite lots of space which you might not have.

Comment: Millions of entries, of nontrivial size.. I'd rather expect they're being stored in a DB.  I'd probably create an indexed column and populate it with the hashes of the existing objects.  This would result in O(logn) run-time lookup, but with realistic memory usage.

Comment: that s what i said, he/she would want to store the thousands in the Dictionary.

Comment: Maps, Dictionaries, and Tables are data structures that can be implemented in user applications (typically in RAM) or other places, but I want to point out that it would make most sense to use a DBMS's implementation to account for the large size.

Comment: @bdares i agree, database would be a persistence alternative for large data.

Comment: They really are not the same object. While the code can be refactored to make them the same object, it is rather hard to do that.  Both foo and bar have many other things that they don't share. And their internal representations of these 100 objects are different.  Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: @user277498 it s not very important if they are not same object or not. your hashcode and equals implementation would do the abstraction.

Comment: So the question becomes: how to write a equals method for these 100 properties.  Is it just foo.prop1 = bar.prop1 && ... && foo.prop100 == bar.prop100? or is there a better way?

Comment: @user277498  if you are matching on those fields, yes!. that s the better way than doing reflection, which would be slower than this.

Comment: @user277498 No, you construct the hash code from these values, then compare `foo.hashCode()` and `bar.hashCode()`

Comment: @brc you need equals implementation as well. if there are collisions, dictionaries uses equals method.

Comment: @brc and when you are querying the dictionary, you dont pass any hashcode, dictionary does that internally. it works on hashcodes of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hash is very nice and simple to implement.. But i want suggest you that algorithm:

1. Map your 100 string properties to one big string(for example concatenate with fixed length for each property) that should unique id of this object. So we have 1000 string in first set, and 1mln strings in second.
2. The problem reduces to find for each strings in second set if first set contains it.
3. Make [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure on first set
4. Complicity of checking if string S in the trie is O(|S|). |S| - length of S.

So... Complicity of algorithm is - O(Sum(|Ai|) + Sum(|Bi|)) = O(max(Sum(|Ai|), Sum(|Bi|)) = O(Sum(|Bi|)) for your problem. Ai - string unique id for first set, Bi - string unique id for second set.

**UPDATE:**
Trie takes O(Sum(|Ai|) * |Alphabet|) space at worst.

Comment: Tries are not space friendly. He can have a very big trie that might consume lots of memory, with hashcode, you are representing an entity with a single number.

Comment: @DarthVader, Generally - yes. But sometimes we have small alphabet or small first set but many queries like "if string contains in first set". And search complicity of string S is **clear** O(|S|).